# onClick not executing on Buttons in Scrollview?

Tags: android, button, scrollview

I have made a vertical linear layout made up of 6 horizontal linear layouts. Each horizontal layout contains 10+ buttons on a scrollview. Below is the main linear layout with one of the horizontal layouts included.

```
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp" 
android:gravity="center"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="75dp">

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button1"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button2"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button3"
            android:text="" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button4"
            android:text="" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button5"
            android:text="" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button6"
            android:text="" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button7"
            android:text="" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button8"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button9"
            android:text="" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bCaitlyn"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:background="@drawable/caitlynsplash"
            android:text="" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button10"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="10.5dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button11"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="11dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button12"
            android:text="" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button13"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="11dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

There seems to be a problem with the onClick command not executing on press. The button is recognizing the touch(as it changes colors) however nothing seems to happen.

```
    package com.LeagueProject;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class Project extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

Button Button1, Button2, Button3, Button4, Button5, Button6, Button7, Button8,
    Button9, Button10, Button11, Button12, Button13;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    projectbuttons();   
    Button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button3.setOnClickListener(this);

}


// Assigned Buttons
private void projectbuttons() {

    Button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    Button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    Button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    Button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    Button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    Button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
    Button10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
    Button11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);
    Button12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);
    Button13 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button13);

}


public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.button1:
        setContentView(R.layout.screen1);
            break;

        case R.id.button2:
        setContentView(R.layout.screen2);
            break;

        case R.id.button3:
        setContentView(R.layout.screen3);
            break;

    }

}
    }
```

Any insight as well as tips/techniques are highly welcomed.

Answer (score 3):

When you `implements View.OnClickListener` in your Activity then you have to 
Override the `onClick()` method else it never executes..

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  .
  .
  .
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

i tried your code using default buttons without giving any images to button and it is working fine... it goes to the corresponding layout....

Comment: even with image for a button works fine here... what exception are you getting?

Comment: When I run it on my phone, It will just stay at the linearlayout screen. I can press all the buttons but nothing will happen. Is this maybe an eclipse error?

Comment: i tried in emulator and works.. just try in emulator once to crosscheck

Comment: ru getting any error log in eclipse....? close ur eclipse and try again with simple button and onclick app

Comment: It seems my eclipse is not recognizing ids created.

Comment: may be your eclipse has a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you need, but you can define the onClick() method within the layout file itself.

```
<Button 
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button1" 
        android:onClick="onClick"
/>
```

Can you try this?